# What is the best way to implement GetHashCode() for class with lots of properties?

Tags: c#, hashcode

I have a class that has lots of properties that I am implementing `IEquitable<T>` on. I have found multiple examples on how to do GetHashCode() for small amount of properties.

[Here is one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
    {
        int hash = 17;
        // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
        hash = hash * 23 + field1.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + field2.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + field3.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

How should I go around when I have hundreds of properties on object?

Comment: Maybe you should rethink your object design? 100s of properties in one class is bad design IMO.

Comment: @Max Absolutely and being contractor offer to my client months of rework without some visible additional functionality.

Comment: Well in that case I would propably use T4 to do that...

Comment: How about loop through the properties?

Comment: @Jite Looping through properties via reflection is not performance friendly ; `GetHashCode` execution time should be as short as possible.

Comment: Is performance important? If not you could use `Reflection` to iterate trough all properties.

Comment: Are all properties significant for the "identity" of the object?

Comment: @Max I was thinking of reflection, cause I will have to do Equals() too. Still it does not feel elegant solution, on the other hand there might not be one when there are 100 of properties. Other way would be to split object adding bunch of interfaces and the do equitable on them and then call all equals on all those objects, in Equals() of this object.

Comment: Related: [See if this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23340717/2530848)

Comment: @Max well, is the execution time a lot longer than it would be if you wrote out all the properties like in the function above (especially when its 100's of properties)?
This would also make it safe if any properties are added or removed... (I'm kinda interested in the answer, why i ask).

Comment: @Max I have had to design dynamic "Equality functions" in the past, often what you will do is do the reflection the first time to build a `Expression<Func<T,int>>` then just compile it and store it in a `Dictionary<Type, Func<T,int>>` and call the pre-built compiled version every time afterward.

Comment: @Jite That is the point of T4. You can set it up to run as soon as the file is saved so any properties added or removed are taken into account in the `GetHashCode` method. And yes the execution time would be a lot longer when using reflection, just try it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best algorithm for overriding GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-overriding-gethashcode)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Calculate hashcode on all property values:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hashCode = this.GetHashCodeOnProperties();
    return hashCode;
}
```

Define this extension method (which is reusable):

```
public static class HashCodeByPropertyExtensions
{
    public static int GetHashCodeOnProperties<T>(this T inspect)
    {
        return inspect.GetType().GetProperties().Select(o => o.GetValue(inspect)).GetListHashCode();
    }

    public static int GetListHashCode<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        return sequence
            .Where(item => item != null)
            .Select(item => item.GetHashCode())
            .Aggregate((total, nextCode) => total ^ nextCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: The hash code will change if any public property changes value.

Comment: Note: if two class instances have the same number of properties, and the same values, the hash code will indicate a match (it will be the same).

Comment: Note: Like all hash codes, it is not guaranteed to be unique. A good use case is deciding whether or not an object has been updated, to save time updating the object in a database or a RESTful call.

Comment: This doesn't account for null property values when calling `item.GetHashCode()` within `GetListHashCode<T>`. It should say `return sequence.Where(item => item != null).Select(item => item.GetHashCode).Aggre.......`

Comment: @ataraxia I'm assuming that it will crash without this change, so this is probably a good change.

Comment: If one of the properties is null then it will crash as you would be calling `item.GetHashCode()` on an `item` that didn't exist. Apart from that it works like a charm.

Comment: I'd want to test the performance here. `GetHashCode` should be blazingly fast; if it's slower than the normal `Equals` check, that's an issue. Reflection isn't known for being very quick, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458/how-costly-is-net-reflection You'd almost want code-gen here, I'd think.

Answer (score 25):

Spend the money to get a tool like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), then just do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> then <kbd>E</kbd>. This will bring up the "Generate Equality Members" dialog

[image]

From there just check the 100 boxes you need and it will autogenerate the `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` functions for you

[image]
(the above took about 10 seconds to create)

Resharper does so much more too that it makes it worth the $150 for a personal license (you can use a personal license for work related activities without violating it, I checked). And if you are not making enough money as a programmer to afford a one time investment of $150 you really should start looking elsewhere to work as you are being very underpaid. (If you don't make any money as a programmer as you are working on a open source project Resharper is [free for development teams of open source projects](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/choose_edition.jsp?license=OPEN_SOURCE))

Comment: I am contractor and cannot influence the tools that my current employer uses, however I could buy personal license just for this, I think it would save enough of time to justify it's cost.

Comment: That is what I did. My employer would not pay for it either, so I bought a personal license for myself and verified that you can use a personal license for "For Hire" work and you can. The [***only*** limitation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/personal_license.html) is if you buy a personal license you ***can not*** be reimbursed for it by your company at a later date.

Comment: So I cannot buy one trough my personal company and do the work for other company that is hiring my personal one, but I can buy a personal license and use it wherever I want?

Comment: If you buy it for your self it will cost $150 and you can use it anywhere. If the consulting company you own buys it for you it will cost $249 (even if you are the only employee) but any single employee of your consulting company can use the software at a given time (if you do have more than one employee). Go read over their Licenses, they are well written and not hard to follow, it makes it very clear.

Comment: Thanks, this seems as my best option at the moment.

Comment: Or save the money and use [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74886665/1112048)

Answer (score 23):

Old questions sometimes have new better answers [HashCode.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode.combine?view=net-6.0):

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return HashCode.Combine(field1, field2, field3);
}
```

Comment: Just good to know the `HashCode` struct is not available in .NET Framework. It was originally added in .NET Core 2.1.

Comment: Thank you. Works great in .net core 3.0

Comment: Hash is different between app launches, doesn't work if you want to store or transmit this hash anywhere and use it between app launches

Comment: @Mando   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.gethashcode?view=net-8.0  says:   <As a result, hash codes should never be used outside of the application domain in which they were created, they should never be used as key fields in a collection, and they should never be persisted.>

Comment: @Mando you should never use the result of `GetHashCode()` method and store it outside the app. Use something like a GUID or [Hashids](https://sqids.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Might use this as well.. Just the overhead being a new instance of everytime you call GetHash().

```
new { A = Prop1, B = Prop2, C = Prop3, D = Prop4 }.GetHashCode();
```

Comment: How is this different from: "int hash = 17;
        
        hash = hash * 23 + field1.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + field2.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + field3.GetHashCode();
        return hash;" I would still have to do it field by field and there is not one class with 100 properties there are quite a few big objects.

Answer (score 1):

If all of those properties contribute to the equality of the object (if you are not overriding equality why are you overriding `GetHashCode`?), then they need to include all those properties in `GetHashCode`.

Remember equal objects *must* have equal hash codes.

Better perhaps to address the question raised in the comment on the question by [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1054649/max) and avoid the situation. Part of this might be to consider if such types should have value semantics (equality defined by their value: is an aggregate of the value of their properties), and switch to reference semantics (each instance is unique).

Comment: Sorry I cannot rewrite whole system, I am contractor and there is more than one massive object, I am looking for a strategy how to deal with this sort of problem.